# Paraceratherium's impact on society, warfare and culture?

Tags: fauna, domestication, pets

So I'm creating a low fantasy world with numerous discrepancies between theirs and ours, one of those being fauna. Specifically pets, livestock, and beasts of burden.

Many different species that have irl gone extinct have been domesticated here for various purposes, like Amphicyonids, Nimravids, etc who are mostly kept as "pets" for kings and emperors, similarly to crocodiles in ancient Egypt or Ashur-bel-kala and his zoo.

But for now, I wanna focus on the Paraceratherium.

What would this animal be used for in a pre-medieval bronze age society? What could it produce? Would it be used for Warfare or is it too skittish? How would people interact with/feel about these animals?

Anything you can come up with is cool!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128865/discussion-on-question-by-ehireoqshfdisxhd-paraceratheriums-impact-on-society).

Answer (score 2):

**Not Much**

Apart from cultural transfusion (in the sense that culture A, with access to animal X, will take on some cultural attributes of culture B, which historically had access to animal Y which is very much like animal X.

Take for example your Paraceratheriums, which per wikipedia lived in areas fairly similar to those Elephants currently live in.  Now a Paraceratherium is bigger than an elephant, true.  It likely lived in small herds, similar to elephants.  They could *probably* move larger loads than elephants.  They could carry more men into battle, but elephants are actually pretty terrible [see here](https://acoup.blog/2019/07/26/collections-war-elephants-part-i-battle-pachyderms/) war animals once ones troops gets over the initial shock.  So they won't prove to be war-winners except maaaaybe in places where you can get hundreds of them easily.  Except they require even more food than elephants, so probably not going to happen.

What do we know about their behavior apart from "probably lived in herds and were grazers?"  Essentially nothing.  So in the end you "just" have an elephant substitute.  A cool one I'll grant you, and if you put it in regions where elephants aren't a thing (say the Siberian populations survived) then you might have some Siberian cultures which use them similar to Carthaginian War Elephants, or beasts of burden.  But in the end, just another elephant. Unless you do something that there isn't any proof for in the paleontological record, like have them produce so much milk a whole village can live off of just one, or make them less ornery than elephants to the point they're more "heavy cavalry" than "elephantry" or something.  Which is cool enough in its own right.  But if you want born-out-by-the-science, they're just a big moderately useful mammal.  Any research into how elephants are and were used would see you right.

Comment: Agreed, and it is a rhinoceros.  So possibly even LESS useful than "elephant substitute"... If we assume it would be as easy to tame and as useful as any rhino.  Wakanda not withstanding, they have proven to be of little use to existing cultures.

Answer (score 1):

The best part about Paraceratheriums is that they are extinct and anything we say about their behavior is conjecture. Maybe they were smart and calm and eager to please.

I'm trying to think outside the box... what would I do with that kind of power, and since there isn't a parallel, I don't think the cultural transfusion works entirely... because with those tall front legs and short rear their towing capacity has to have been stupefying... I'm thinking of whole mobile villages... houses and shops on sledges, pulled by the family Para...

Ships that had Para treadmills powering giant water wheels...

Maybe they could run... unlike a elephant which is NOT built for that... a Para at top speed?

Comment: oooooh interesting